# swift code core data fetchrequest

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm going crazy trying to retrieve a fact for a given question in Core data. The code I'm using is below and what I'd like to do is let the user select a "question" and see the related "facts" for it.

I'm going around in circles trying to do this. Can anyone explain to me what I'm missing? Thank you

```
      let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext



    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "BadHusband")

    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "question= %@", itemSelected)

    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false


    do {

        let results = try managedContext.fetch(request)

        stuff = results as! [NSManagedObject]

        if results.count > 0 {

            for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {


                if let question = result.value(forKey: "question"), let facts = result.value(forKey: "facts") {

              print(question)
                print(facts)
                }

            }


        }
```

Comment: What is happening here? Where are you facing the problem, which line?

Comment: The problem is that I can get the "question" value back from core data but I can't get the "facts" information back. Which is the point of what I'm trying to do. Thanks Rajan